# ultimate virtual solution for testing <=IE8 browsers

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I need to know of a solution to run a local test server through a virtual guest. I am able to use Virtual PC as well as most the other solutions. My current workaround is to deploy to Tomcat on Windows 7 and test the main current browsers there. I am also able to mount share my Tomcat instance to Ubuntu so am able to run the same app without redeploying.

Currently I just invested on a Windows upgrade to be able to try out Microsofts ie8 and down VHDs but the best I am able to do with this is deploy to production server and then run the ie6, ie7 and ie8 browsers which is very time consuming.

Any suggestions or pointers for me? Ultimately a working solution to run these VHds or browsers in VirtualBox would be ideal for me, as I am familiar with it.

Related to my question I have come across some useful tutorials that may help others who find this question:

[Virtual PC solution for legacy IE browsers in Windows 7](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2009/06/24/using-windows-7s-xp-mode-to-run-ie-6-and-ie-7-side-by-side/) 
[VmWare solution](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10911/run-xp-mode-on-windows-7-machines-without-hardware-virtualization/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is as follows & will only work with upgraded Windows 7 (not home premium).
Uninstall IE9 update to bring back IE8, IE9 seems to support css3 well, so testing in FF7 should be good enough for IE9.

Then follow [this](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2009/06/24/using-windows-7s-xp-mode-to-run-ie-6-and-ie-7-side-by-side/) tutorial and repeat the process for as many virtual browsers you want. Note
I did include IE8 but don't use it as it's slower to run a virtual PC than native IE8 just in case I wish to reinstall IE9.

I use quirks mode in IE8 to test for IE7 and IE6 can go to Davy Jones Locker :D

When using xpmode, you must copy the xp disk each time without any updates and start process from scratch.

I also use VirtualBox to test Linux browsers as it's faster than Virtual PC and I share test server (Tomcat) so am able to run same instance without redeploying.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one Windows version (XP, Win7 will be fine) and install IETester:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: And how do I access my local local test url from this tool? I just downloaded it and it looks a poorer solution than just running original ie6, ie7 and ie8 browsers seamlessly from a virtual system.